# javascript and jquery date format conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert date from this format `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"`
to `Mon, May 09 2016 08:12:29` using JavaScript, below code is not working. pls advice

```
var str2 = "2016-05-09T08:12:29.110";
var date2 = Date.parse( str2 );
alert( date2.toString( 'EEE, MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss' ) );`
```

Comment: Date::toString don't accept parameter. You can try http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Sorry.. I dont want to include any external js, but this is working alert( date2.toString( 'MM-dd-yyyy' ) ); how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var str2 = "2016-05-09T08:12:29.110";
var date2 = new Date(Date.parse(str2));
var days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
function pad(n, number) {
  var str = number.toString();
  var result = '';
  for (var i=0; i<n-str.length; ++i) {
    result += '0';
  }
  return result + str;
}
document.body.innerHTML = days[date2.getDay()] + ', ' + months[date2.getMonth()] + ' ' + pad(2, date2.getDate()) + ' ' + date2.getFullYear() + ' ' + pad(2, date2.getUTCHours()) + ':' + pad(2, date2.getMinutes()) + ':' + pad(2, date2.getSeconds());
```

Comment: Its working after change line number two as : var date2 = new Date(str2); thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var str2 = "2016-05-09T08:12:29.110";
var date2 =new Date(str2);
alert( date2 );
```

Comment: Thanks.. partially working. output: EEE, May 9 2016 08:12:29, day is not coming. pls advice

Comment: In JavaScript, we cannot directly format date as per our requirement. Means there is no any ready-made method. So you have to create your own custom method to format date as per your requirement.